# How to avoid alltt skipping a line?

Tags: line-breaking

The environment `alltt` skips a line before and after its use. Is there a way to modify this behaviour to avoid these empty lines ?

*** Edit
I tried to get inspired by a [similar post about figure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1569922/4444546) but I am a noob and don't really understand how to modify the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like most latex displays it is a list and so has `\topsep` spacing above it (note thiis is stretchable vertical space not really a blankline) You can set it to 0 eiether inline or in a `\newenvironment` definition

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alltt}
\begin{document}

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
{\setlength\topsep{0pt}\begin{alltt}
one two three
four five six
\end{alltt}}%
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{document}
```

---

to redefine `alltt` to always do this you can use

```
\let\oldalltt\alltt
\let\endoldalltt\endalltt
\renewenironment{alltt}{\setlength\topsep{0pt}\oldalltt}{\endoldalltt}
```

Comment: thanks, but this affect all the list-type environment then? is there a way to redefine the `alltt` environment (with `\renewenvironment` like in the mentioned question)  to alter only `alltt`?

Comment: @clemlaflemme as above it only affects _this_ instance (note the `{}` group around the setting. simplest definition if you want lots of these is just `\newenvironment{alltt2}{\setlength\topsep{0pt}\alltt}{\endalltt}`

Comment: the main thing is that I use `knitr` which produce `.tex` with `alltt`  environments. That's why I'd like to redefine this environment, and not define to define a new one with another name.

Comment: @clemlaflemme sigh, you could have said:-)  I'll add something to the answer

Comment: thanks, I just had to add `\let\oldendalltt\endalltt` and `\renewenvironment{alltt}{\setlength\topsep{0pt}\oldalltt}{\oldendalltt}` instead, it seems like the process never ended

Comment: last comment: it appears that the global solution redefining `alltt` environment make `dev="tikz"` knitr option fail

Comment: @clemlaflemme I added the saving of the end code, sorry, can't help with knitr

Comment: `tikzDevice` R function does wired things no worries